# ОС не входящие в семейство UNIX и NT

Tags: ос

Меня давно мучает вопрос : есть ли операционные системы отличные от UNIX(то есть не дистрибутив `Linux`, не `ОS X`, и т.д.) и Windows NT? Искал долго, максимум, что хоть как-то подподало под мои критерии - к примеру **`AmigaOS`**(https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AmigaOS). Но всё-равно не совсем то. Если ли что-то по-настоящему уникальное, и отличное от `UNIX` и `NT`?

P.S.: я имею в виду ОС с графическим интерфейсом(не консолечка, всмысле).
P.P.S.: мобильные ОСи и "вышедшие из моды" не считаются, только ПК

Comment: А как же [**DOS**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS)? :-)

Comment: @approximatenumber, ой я забыл написать, что я имел в виду графические системы)

Comment: Графическое окружение обычно является лишь частью ОС, точней, оно находится в ОС уже на верхнем уровне, а само понятие ОС... оно немного из другой категории. А на DOS`e, кстати, вполне себе графика работает.

Comment: @approximatenumber, ну хорошо, согласен DOS, и что всё?

Comment: Ну тогда продолжайте уточнять, что не имели ввиду телефоны, что не имели ввиду оси, которые вышли уже "из моды".

Comment: @MaxZS, без проблем

Comment: Ну так те же Symbian ОS, BlackBerry OS.

Comment: Например Solaris. Есть еще Haiku

Comment: @carapuz, а Solaris, разве не  UNIX?

Comment: @carapuz, ну да Haiku, она вроде не UNIX, но всё равно: тот же рабочий стол, та же панель(в BeOs). Ну всё одинаково как-то..

Comment: OS/2 еще забыли, правда сейчас она не особо актуальна, но она была графической (windows много идей из нее перенял), работала на персоналках и не unix

Comment: @carapuz
Solaris это всё же UNIX-подобное. В основе там BSD + System V.

Comment: А Солярис действительно Unix, типичная System V

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC. Похоже, только ReactOS, но это тоже NT-подобная ОС.

Comment: QNX подобен UNIX, но не является ни дистрибутивом линуха, ни осх, ни какого-либо другого юних.

Comment: [KolibriOS](http://kolibrios.org/ru/) например.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amoeba:  https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amoeba_%28%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%29
Написано, что "разрабатывалась с нуля".

Comment: О, хоть, она и "вышла из моды", но мне понравилась фраза `написана с нуля`. Наверно, это то что я искал